# SignalR to call remote SOAP web service?

Tags: web-services, web, signalr

Does anybody did before something like that? May be some examples or articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you're looking at the wrong technology. WCF supports SOAP though.

Comment: Yes, I know, just interesting about possibility to use this library for such kind of job.

Comment: No, you cannot use SignalR to do *anything* with SOAP